# How to handle incorrect argparse default

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using [ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter) to print out the default values for each argument in my parser. It works great in most cases, but I can't get it to work correctly in the following scenario.

```
parser.add_argument('--keep-subsets', dest='remove_subsets',
                    default=True, action='store_false',
                    help='Keep individual subsets')
```

The default user-facing behavior is to *NOT* keep the subsets, so the usage statement should report `default: False`. However, the internal implementation uses the negated logic: a variable named `remove_subsets` indicating whether the subsets should be removed. The code above gives the following in the usage statement.

```
--keep-subsets        Keep individual subsets (default: True)
```

One solution of course would be to logically negate the internal implementation and pass a `keep_subsets` variable instead of a `remove_subsets` variable. This would allow us to use the `store_true` action and `default: False`, which would result in the correct usage statement.

But assuming messing with the internal implementation is not an option, is there a way to handle this scenario correctly?

Comment: For get about the keep/remove names for the moment.  Does the `store_false` logic make sense for '--foo' argument?  If the flag isn't used the value will be `True` (the default); if it is provided the value will be `False`.  That's what 'store_false' means.  'store_true' and 'store_false' are just specialized cases of 'store_const'.

Comment: The issue is discussed in https://bugs.python.org/issue28742.  As I point out there, you don't have to use `ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter`.  All it does is add '%(default)s' to the help strings.  You can just as easily do that yourself, and omit it where the value is misleading.

Comment: And here, https://bugs.python.org/issue27153

Comment: @hpaulj After having a week to reflect on this, I agree with your sentiments. If you want to move these to an answer, I'd be happy to upvote and accept the answer to acknowledge your helpful feedback. Thanks!